# how to store data in angular 5 localstorage

Tags: arrays, json, ionic3, angular5, local-storage

```
userData = {
    items: [
      { medicine_id: "", medicine_qty: 1, priscription_path: "" }
     { medicine_id: "", medicine_qty: 1, priscription_path: "" }
     { medicine_id: "", medicine_qty: 1, priscription_path: "" }
    ],
    user_id: "",
    store_id: "",
  };
```

I want to store data like this in my local storage using angular 5.  Using interface class

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage

Comment: why to use external NPM module, when you can do.. using native browser API @AlexanderPoshtaruk

Answer (score 3):

In your example, since userData is an object you must first use **JSON.stringify** to convert it into string and then store in local storage.

```
localStorage.getItem('userData',JSON.stringify(userData))
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
```

then after conversion, you can use:

to store the item in the localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('item_name','content');
```

to retrieve the stored item (using key name):

```
localStorage.getItem('item_name');
```